# Code for rolling filter in python behaving oddly (Numpy Arrays)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, moving-average

I wanted to implement a simple rolling average filter in python using numpy.sum()

Given x is a numpy array of first 30 natural numbers. (x = np.linspace(1, 30, 30))

np.sum(x[8:10]) returns 19 which is right as x[8] = 9 and x[9] = 10

But when i do the following i get some random values.(here i chose 2 as the size of the window)

```
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(1, 30, 30)

print(x)

y = x #creating a duplicate array of same length  
z= len(x) 

for i in range(2,z):
    y[i] = np.sum(x[i-2:i]) 


print(y/2,"\n")
print(y,"\n")
print(x)
```

The result i get is

```
[ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9. 10. 11. 12. 13. 14. 15. 16. 17. 18.
 19. 20. 21. 22. 23. 24. 25. 26. 27. 28. 29. 30.]
[5.000000e-01 1.000000e+00 1.500000e+00 2.500000e+00 4.000000e+00
 6.500000e+00 1.050000e+01 1.700000e+01 2.750000e+01 4.450000e+01
 7.200000e+01 1.165000e+02 1.885000e+02 3.050000e+02 4.935000e+02
 7.985000e+02 1.292000e+03 2.090500e+03 3.382500e+03 5.473000e+03
 8.855500e+03 1.432850e+04 2.318400e+04 3.751250e+04 6.069650e+04
 9.820900e+04 1.589055e+05 2.571145e+05 4.160200e+05 6.731345e+05] 

[1.000000e+00 2.000000e+00 3.000000e+00 5.000000e+00 8.000000e+00
 1.300000e+01 2.100000e+01 3.400000e+01 5.500000e+01 8.900000e+01
 1.440000e+02 2.330000e+02 3.770000e+02 6.100000e+02 9.870000e+02
 1.597000e+03 2.584000e+03 4.181000e+03 6.765000e+03 1.094600e+04
 1.771100e+04 2.865700e+04 4.636800e+04 7.502500e+04 1.213930e+05
 1.964180e+05 3.178110e+05 5.142290e+05 8.320400e+05 1.346269e+06] 

[1.000000e+00 2.000000e+00 3.000000e+00 5.000000e+00 8.000000e+00
 1.300000e+01 2.100000e+01 3.400000e+01 5.500000e+01 8.900000e+01
 1.440000e+02 2.330000e+02 3.770000e+02 6.100000e+02 9.870000e+02
 1.597000e+03 2.584000e+03 4.181000e+03 6.765000e+03 1.094600e+04
 1.771100e+04 2.865700e+04 4.636800e+04 7.502500e+04 1.213930e+05
 1.964180e+05 3.178110e+05 5.142290e+05 8.320400e+05 1.346269e+06]
```

Comment: `y = x ` does not create a duplicate or copy.  `y` references the same array as `x`

Answer (score 0):

try that maybe solve your problem

```
y = x.copy()
```

Comment: Thanks that helped. Also I do know other ways to solve the problem but just wanted to know what was causing the issue here and why

Comment: Since x and y are the same, you are adding numbers recursively, so you get very large numbers.

Comment: so when I do y = x python assigns y the same address as x ?

Comment: yes so you should use "copy"